# solution of equation $\sin z = 10^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

solution will be
$\sin z = 10^3$
options: A z=(4n+1)pi/2+iarccosh(10^3)
B:z=(4n+1)pi/2
C:arccos(10^3)
D:none
answer first is correct
so here I first expand it like this and got two equations so how to solve these two equations and find solutions

I'm having difficulties with hyperbolic function
I have to solution of $Z$? I tried to expand it with $x+iy$ but stuck when comparing two equations
$sin(x+iy)=sinx coshy+ i cosx sinhy$=10^3
by comparing we got
sinx coshy=10^3
$$\sin x\times \cosh y =10^3$$

Comment: Do you know how to express $\sin z$ in terms of $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$?

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Comment: Yes. I put them in $e^z$ terms. First i put it sin(x+iy) terms then expand

Comment: Answer is $(4n+1) pie/2 + i cosh^-1(10^3)$

Comment: As $\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x) \cosh(y) + i\cos(x) \sinh(y)$, you have 2 equations $\sin(x) \cosh(y)=19^3$ **and** $\cos(x) \sinh(y)=0$. Either $y=0$ which is not possible or $y \ne 0$ giving $\cos(x)=0 \implies x=(2k+1)\pi/2$ (in fact $x=4k+1)\pi/2$ because the sine must be positive in the first equation) and you are reduced to $\cosh(y)=19^3$...

Comment: How did you change 2k+1 to 4k+1

Comment: thank you very much jean marie

Answer (score 0):

using euler formula
sin(z)=$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$
you get the following:
$$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2000i$$
multiply both sides by $e^{iz}$ and you get:
$$e^{2iz} - 2000ie^{iz}-1=0$$
$\Delta=-4000000+4$ so $\sqrt{\Delta}=3i\sqrt{111111}$

So:
$e^{iz_1}=(1000-3\sqrt{111111})i $  and $ e^{iz_2} = (1000+3\sqrt{111111})i$

$$z_1=-ilog(i(1000-3\sqrt{111111}))$$ and $$z_2 =-ilog(i(1000+3\sqrt{111111}))$$

Comment: You could take the $i$ out of the logarithms, giving a $\pi i/2$ term.